# How do you do println() in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I cant seem to find out how to do `println()` in Swift 2.

I tried doing `println(helloworld)`

That doesn't work

helloworld is a variable

Comment: print and println function has been merged to a single method in Swift2. It is available in Xcode7 beta.

Comment: If you type `println("Hello world")` in Xcode 7, the error message *"'println' has been renamed to print"* immediately pops up, together with a *"Fix it: replace 'println' by 'print'"* suggestion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it's `print("hello world")`. it's changed in swift 2.0 and you need to see Apple's website. put `print()` instead of `println()`

Comment: print(hello world) won't work. :) It should be print(hello, world) if hello and world are variables. Or print(helloworld) if helloworld is a variable.

Comment: great............

Answer (score 21):

**No More `println()`** As per apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs5printu0_Rq0_Ss16OutputStreamType_FTq_Rq0__T_) :

In Swift 2.0 there is

```
print("Hello")
```

for the new line you can set flag

```
print("Hello", appendNewline: false)
```

> Declaration
>
> func print(_ value: T, appendNewline appendNewline: Bool)
>
> Discussion
>
> The textual representation is obtained from the value using its
>   protocol conformances, in the following order of preference:
>   Streamable, CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible. If
>   none of these conformances are found, a default text representation is
>   constructed in an implementation-defined way, based on the type kind
>   and structure.

Comment: Is it just me, or does it require "Swift.print()" sometimes? It literally opens up printing options. Xcode 7.1 Beta 2.

Comment: If you are building OS X Applications you'll need to do swift.print(...) - print(...) is for  the printer dialog box.

Comment: @MortenGustafsson Thanks for information. But question is of iOS not OS X.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I Know, I was answering Naoto Ida's comment. :) Sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: @MortenGustafsson It's Ok. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use quotation marks:

```
println("helloworld")
```

and in swift 2.0, use print():

```
print("helloworld")
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Xcode 7.0 Beta 6, the solution on my end, including getting rid of the annoying new line character:

[image]