# How to println by swift in terminal?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to run `./swift -emit-executable shape.swift` by terminal

*shape.swift*

```
class Shape
{
    let name:String = ""

    init(name:String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }

    let anyShape = Shape.init(name:"Jaum")
    println("Name, \(anyShape.name).")
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
shape.swift:11:5: error: expected declaration
    println("Name, \(anyShape.name).")
    ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have declarations at the root level of a class, move them outside.

Don't use `.init` to create a class instance.

Use `print` instead of `println` (it has [changed in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217024/how-do-you-do-println-in-swift-2)).

And don't give a value of `""` to your immutable`name` if you want to use the initializer, just declare the type.

```
class Shape {

    let name:String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }

}

let anyShape = Shape(name:"Jaum")

print("Name, \(anyShape.name).")
```

Last note, it's not `swift` but `swiftc` which is able to create an executable:

```
swiftc -emit-executable shape.swift
```